# Why does the Scroll event unnecessarily fire when a ListView is loaded in (Xamarin.)Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin.Android app. I have a `ListView` that has the following code:

```
OnCreate
{   
    //other code here
    listView.Scroll += ListView_Scroll;
}

private void ListView_Scroll(object sender, AbsListView.ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

(I simply added the `Scroll += ...` and the Empty Project to the [Custom Row Views project](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/CustomRowView) of Xamarin Android.

Immediately when the list is loaded, it throws the `NotImplementedException`. Even when `Adapter` is null, it still scrolls!

Why does it scroll when it does not need to? The `ScrollState` also changes to `Fling`.

Can someone explain why this happens? I am working on an app that uses this event and this is very annoying to work around.

I don't know if this also happens in Android but I assume it does, that's why I have tagged Android, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView in Android doesn't inherit from Scrollview but is very similar to the same

> The list-view module is using android.widget.ListView for its Android implementation while behind ScrollView lies android.widget.HorizontalScrolView (or vertical) so basically we have two different native controls with different implementations. Comparing to HorizontalScrollView, the ListView for Android presets much more functionality for listing data and also has specific optimisations so this is the logical choice to implement in nativeScript as well.

Secondly it throws that exception because you have the following line  in your scroll event  :

```
 throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Removing this should solve your problem for the most part.

> Why does it scroll when it does not need to?

What actually happens here is that the listview Scrolls To the current Position

Goodluck Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 

I know WHY it throws the exception, the scroll event is called and when it is, the exception is thrown. The EXCEPTION isn't the problem, I just put it there to prove that the scroll happens on startup.   In my app I (of course) have different code there.

I don't really like that it calls the scroll event when it has nothing to scroll to. I don't see any scroll action happening when an empty list is loaded so there shouldn't be a scroll event happening IMO. Even when `Enabled` is set to `false`, it will still call this event...

Comment: Android by default calls this as it calls the function i mentioned above so you cannot do anything about it, you can even check native android for the same i.e. in android studio and it will still call the scroll event